# Comment out certain blocks of code using single-line comments

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, find-replace

I have a source code file where I want to comment out (using single-line comments) certain blocks that have a specific opening and ending pattern. For example:

```
1
2
BEGIN
3
4
END
5
6
```

I want the output to be of the form:

```
1
2
//BEGIN
//3
//4
//END
5
6
```

I have tried to use `sed`, and I can match the whole block, but what I can't figure out is how to get each line of that match and perform another `sed` operation to replace the start of the line with the two forward slashes.

**Edit:** the `BEGIN` and `END` can also be on the same line.

Answers using any other tool are also welcome. Also, kindly provide an explanation for your code for beginners like me!

Comment: `sed '/BEGIN/,/END/s%^%//%' ` Look at sed's ranges

Comment: It fails if there is a stray `END` somewhere in the code